# How to avoid TStringList.SaveToFile overwriting my previous changes?

Tags: file, delphi, frame, firemonkey, tabcontrol

I'm trying to write my `TStringList` into a TXT file (`mydbtxt.txt`).

I have two source files, the MainForm and a Frame. In my MainForm, there is a TabControl and a Button, where I can dynamically add more tabs. When tabs are added, the Frame will be the `Parent` of the new tabs.

When I add a new tab and fill up some data into it, my second tab will always overwrite my first tab. Please help, the latest keeps on overwriting my previous record.

Please refer to my image:

[image]

```
procedure TForm1.bSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  strList: TStringList;
  i:integer;
begin
  strList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to TabControl1.TabCount - 1 do
    begin
      strList.Delimiter := ' ';
      strList.QuoteChar := ',';
      strList.Add('PlanName,SavingAccount,InitialCapital,TopUp,Every,RemindOn,CashOutBy,Percentage,TotalInitialCapital' +#13#10
                              + profileFrame.plan_title.Text +','
                              + profileFrame.savingAccount_edit.Text +','
                              + profileFrame.initialCapital_edit.Text +','
                              + profileFrame.topUp_edit.Text +','
                              + profileFrame.every_comboBox.Selected.Text +','
                              + profileFrame.remindOn_comboBox.Selected.Text +','
                              + profileFrame.cashOutBy_comboBox.Selected.Text +','
                              + profileFrame.percentage_edit.Text +','
                              + profileFrame.initialCapital_edit.Text);
    end;
    strList.SaveToFile(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + TPath.PathSeparator + 'mydbtxt.txt');

  finally
    strList.Free;
  end;

end;
```

This is how I create my Frame, and how I add my Frame into the TabControl:

```
procedure TForm1.AddNewTab;
begin
  profileFrame := TProfileFrame.Create(Self);

  //TabItem
  TabItem := TabControl1.Add();
  inc(tab_name_Count);
  tabItem.Text := tab_name_Count.ToString;
  //
  profileFrame.Parent := tabItem;

end;
```

Comment: The problem is that your `strList.Add` line doesn't refer to `i`. You add the same line over and over again. `profileFrame` isn't going to refer to different frames each time. It is always the same thing. It doesn't know about your loop or `i`. What you need to do is to refer to the `i`th frame in iteration `i`. Didn't you use an object list? Then do `FMyFrames[i].plan_title.Text` and so on.

Comment: (Also, you forgot to tell us what `profileFrame` is in your case. Is it a global variable? Where is it defined? Where is it assigned to? Not that it is relevant for the solution, though.)

Comment: In addition, you can remove the lines setting the delimiter and quote char, since you don't use the name-value functionality of the `TStringList` at all. And even if you did, you should have been setting these outside the loop (before it).

Comment: Hi Sir i have add something to my question already. Could you please guide me?

Comment: But where is the `TObjectList` we have been talking about? You need to add a `FFrames: TObjectList<TProfileFrame>` to the `private` section of your `TForm1` class declaration, create this in `FormCreate` (`FFrames := TObjectList<TProfileFrame>.Create(False)` say), free it in `FormDestroy` (`FFrames.Free`) and add each new frame to it in `AddNewTab`: `FFrames.Add(profileFrame)`. Your `profileFrame` variable will always refer to the last added frame, because you overwrite this variable every time! But now you can refer to `FFrame[0], FFrame[1], ...` to access each individual frame.

Comment: But when i created the TObjectList, it shows that it is a undeclared identifier. This is how i create:

private 
FFrames:TObjectList<TProfileFrame>;

in the FormCreate:
FFrames := TObjectList<TProfileFrame>.Create(False);

and finally on Destroy:
FreeAndNill(FFrames)

Comment: im not sure why is it when i create it, its error and red line appears

Comment: If you look in the documentation for [`TObjectList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList), you see that it is declared in the `Generics.Collections` unit. Hence, you need to add `Generics.Collections` to the `uses` clause in the `interface` section.

Comment: Yes Sir! It works now thank you! But why is it when i try to add in Stringlist.Add(),  FFrame[i].plan_title.Text is still undeclared identifier?

Comment: Because you misspelled `FFrames` without the `s`?

Comment: Yessss. Thank you so muchhhhhh! You are my motivation to be a better programmer! You are remarkably observant!!!! Thank you!! (Bow)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a single `profileFrame` variable that you are re-assigning each time `AddNewTab()` is called.  In `bSaveClick()`, you are using that same variable in a loop, so of course every line added to the `TStringList` is going to have the same data.  Because you are not accessing the individual `TProfileFrame` objects that you previously created.  You are accessing only the last `TProfileFrame` that you created.

Since each `TProfileFrame` object is a child of a `TTabItem`, you can try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.bSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  strList: TStringList;
  i:integer;
  TabItem: TTabItem;
  profileFrame: TProfileFrame;
begin
  strList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to TabControl1.TabCount - 1 do
    begin
      TabItem := TabControl1.Tabs[i];
      profileFrame := TabItem.Children[0] as TProfileFrame;
      strList.Add('PlanName,SavingAccount,InitialCapital,TopUp,Every,RemindOn,CashOutBy,Percentage,TotalInitialCapital');
      strList.Add(profileFrame.plan_title.Text +','
                + profileFrame.savingAccount_edit.Text +','
                + profileFrame.initialCapital_edit.Text +','
                + profileFrame.topUp_edit.Text +','
                + profileFrame.every_comboBox.Selected.Text +','
                + profileFrame.remindOn_comboBox.Selected.Text +','
                + profileFrame.cashOutBy_comboBox.Selected.Text +','
                + profileFrame.percentage_edit.Text +','
                + profileFrame.initialCapital_edit.Text);
    end;
    strList.SaveToFile(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'mydbtxt.txt');
  finally
    strList.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.AddNewTab;
var
  TTabItem: TTabItem;
  profileFrame: TProfileFrame;
begin
  profileFrame := TProfileFrame.Create(Self);

  //TabItem
  TabItem := TabControl1.Add();
  inc(tab_name_Count);
  tabItem.Text := tab_name_Count.ToString;
  //
  profileFrame.Parent := tabItem;

end;
```

---

That being said, there is no need to duplicate the column names for each record that is added to the `TStringList`.  That will just pollute the text file and make it harder to read.  Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.bSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  strList: TStringList;
  i:integer;
  TabItem: TTabItem;
  profileFrame: TProfileFrame;
begin
  strList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    strList.Add('PlanName,SavingAccount,InitialCapital,TopUp,Every,RemindOn,CashOutBy,Percentage,TotalInitialCapital');
    for i := 0 to TabControl1.TabCount - 1 do
    begin
      TabItem := TabControl1.Tabs[i];
      profileFrame := TabItem.Children[0] as TProfileFrame;
      strList.Add(profileFrame.plan_title.Text +','
                + profileFrame.savingAccount_edit.Text +','
                + profileFrame.initialCapital_edit.Text +','
                + profileFrame.topUp_edit.Text +','
                + profileFrame.every_comboBox.Selected.Text +','
                + profileFrame.remindOn_comboBox.Selected.Text +','
                + profileFrame.cashOutBy_comboBox.Selected.Text +','
                + profileFrame.percentage_edit.Text +','
                + profileFrame.initialCapital_edit.Text);
    end;
    strList.SaveToFile(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'mydbtxt.txt');
  finally
    strList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Then the file will look more like this:

[image]